# Android App doesn't notice when I've signed up to a site

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, sign-up

On Friday, I joined the [Anime & Manga beta site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) **on a PC** in order to [ask a question about Trigun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14532/how-does-trigun-maximum-relate-to-its-predecessors-the-trigun-anime-and-manga). The Stack Exchange app was open on my phone already at this point, and I did not exit it.

Later on, I got a notification on my phone about having received an answer. It was a good one! When I tried to upvote the answer using the Android app, though, I wasn't allowed to: it said I hadn't joined the site, apparently not having caught up with the fact I had done so a couple of hours beforehand.

I apologise for the [low battery indicator](http://xkcd.com/1373/) in these screenshots. :) I plugged it in to charge minutes later, I promise!

> [image: The app says: "You're not a member of Anime & Manga yet. Would you like to join?"]

When I said I wanted to join, though, I couldn't, unsurprisingly, on account of already having done so:

> [image: An error message: "You are already a member of Anime & Manga."]

I closed the app entirely and reopened it, and then the app was happy that I was a member of Anime & Manga. But it wasn't updated *whilst* the app was running.

The app should probably get informed of this. (Though this may be low priority due to not occurring all that often.)

This occurred on the Android App v1.0.51 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.3.

Comment: ...and it got worse: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262098/android-app-crashes-when-trying-to-join-an-se-that-i-had-already-joined :/

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed as of any version greater than 1.0.81, sorry it took so long!