# Android app crashes when trying to join an SE that I had already joined

Tags: bug, android-app, user-accounts

The Android app crashes when trying to join an SE that I had already joined:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like escalation of [this other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242322/android-app-doesnt-notice-when-ive-signed-up-to-a-site), which never got fixed. (now instead of just a misleading banner, it crash)